# Calculate percentile in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set named  join2 like this

```
   pd.DataFrame({'id' : [197, 220, 278, 300, 303, 318, 326, 339, 354, 382, 407, 432, 433, 440, 441, 447, 454, 501, 504, 508, 550, 564,601, 602, 606,628,643, 668,688,718], 'count' : [10, 5, 5, 5,15, 5, 5, 25, 10, 5, 5, 5, 20, 15, 5, 5, 10, 10, 10, 5, 5,5,5, 5,10,10,5, 10, 15, 5]
, 'sum' : [6, 3, 5, 3, 11, 1, 4, 13, 4, 3, 1, 5, 16, 9, 1, 5, 8, 10, 10, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 6, 10, 1, 6, 15, 5],
'percentage' : [60.0,60.0,100.0,60.0,73.33333333333333,20.0,80.0,52.0,40.0,60.0,20.0,100.0,80.0,60.0,20.0,100.0,80.0,100.0,100.0,80.0,100.0,100.0, 100.0,80.0, 60.0, 100.0, 20.0, 60.0, 100.0, 100.0]})
```

and I want to add a new column named percentile.

I have tried both these

```
    join2['pctile'] = join2['percentage'].rank(pct=True)
and 
    sz = join2['percentage'].size-1
    join2['pctile'] = join2['percentage'].rank(method='max').apply(lambda x: 100.0*(x-1)/sz)
```

but the percentiles that I am getting are not correct. Percentile should be 25% where the percentage is 60%. How can I solve this?

Comment: What is expected output for all rows?

Comment: im confused why the percentile should be 25 for 60 percentage

Comment: @jezrael I want the percentile of each value in percentage column in a new column ie pctile

Comment: Yes, so what are expected numbers?

Comment: expected numbers are like this -  25 percentile for 60 % , 100 percentile for 100% , etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this `method='average'` instead of `'method='min'`:

```
df['pctile'] = df['percentage'].rank(method='average').apply(lambda x: 100.0*(x-1)/sz)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
    id  count  sum  percentage  pctile
0  197     10    6          60    25.0
1  220      5    3          60    25.0
2  278      5    5         100   100.0
3  300      5    3          60    25.0
4  303     15   11          73    75.0
```

Click here for the [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rank.html?highlight=rank#pandas.Series.rank) to pandas documentation for `.rank()`

Comment: I have updated  my dataframe. Can you please check the solution that you gave in this as it is not giving correct o/p in this data set

Comment: the answer looks correct, can you indicate the expected output? Are you expecting percentile to be 100 when the percentage is 100?

Comment: yes. but when I am applying this in my updated data set it's not giving the desired output. What you have done is exactly what I am looking for but for this updated data.

Comment: I'd recommend that you create 3 columns, `df['pctile_min']`, `df['pctile_avg']` and `df['pctile_max']`, with `method='min'`, `method='average'` and `method='max'` respectively and look at which set of results best fit what you are looking for. You might have a slightly different understanding of percentile from the conventional understanding. If we go by the definition in Wikipedia, you should be using `method='min'`.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is `DataFrame.quantile()`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id' : [197, 220, 278,300,303], 'count' : [10,5,5,5,15], 'sum' : [6,3,5,3,11], 'percentage' : [60,60,100,60,73]})
```

To be 70% quantile

```
df1.quantile(0.7)
```

Comment: avoid images unless necessary, helps folks who browse on phones and don't wish to waste data, and big images hinder readability.

Comment: The idea of adding the return value of your proposed solution is good - just don't do it as an image; post it as code formatted text. Often people post it as code comments, then it's greyed hence readable but somehow a little in the background against the solution itself.